# What is the starting value for the sorcery skill when learned spontaneously?

Tags: basic-role-playing, laundry

The Laundry RPG book says that when you pass 50% or 75% in one of a set of particular skills you get a check to learn sorcery skill, but I can't find anywhere that it says what value it starts at if you pass the check.   One of my players is playing a Type III Deep One hybrid, which per the description in the Agent's Handbook get a check to learn sorcery when their Call of the Deep taint reaches those thresholds.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6534). Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer from knowledge of BRP (4th edition/Call of Cthulhu) not the Laundry RPG, which I haven't played, so take this answer with a big ol' grain of salt.

In general, in BRP, you get skill advancement checks when you succeed in a skill check that advances the scenario. In 6th edition Call of Cthulhu, at the end of the scenario, you roll each skill that got a check during the scenario. If the roll **rolls over** the current level of the skill, you add +1d10 points to the skill.

Judging from what you've said, I'd read it as you get a skill check for sorcery. At the end of the scenario (or whenever The Laundry says you do advancement), you'd roll your sorcery. Since it starts at 00% (check the base value on the [character sheet](http://cubicle7.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/TheLaundryCharacterSheet.pdf)), should be no need to roll, you couldn't possibly roll under 00%. Then, add +1d10 to the skill (or whatever die The Laundry normally uses to improve skills).

Comment: Given that the question is "What value does Sorcery skill start at in Laundry?", shouldn't this answer provide some reasoning to back up its assumption that Sorcery skill starts at 00% in Laundry?

Comment: Sure. It's on the [character sheet](http://cubicle7.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/TheLaundryCharacterSheet.pdf), which lists all the base values for the skills